# Java compile error: Cannot Find Symbol for BufferedReader

Tags: java

Hey I'm just starting my first programming book on java so this should be an easy fix. Messing around with my fresh knowledge of conditionals and I'm getting the title error.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Hello {  
   public static void main (String args[]) { 

   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);
   InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

   String str;

   System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
   str = br.readLine();  

   System.out.println(str);
   System.out.println("Welcome to the world of Java Programming!"); 
  }
}
```

When I tried to compile:

```
Hello.java:6:error:cannot find symbol
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);

symbol: variable ip
location: class Hello
1 error
```

Answer (score 4):

You are referencing `ip` before it's declared. 
Change the order to:

```
InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with making import static like,
**import static java.lang.System.in;**

Answer (score 1):

You are defining ip later and using it before creating thats why giving that error

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);
   InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :-

```
import java.io.*;

public class Hello {  
   public static void main (String args[]) { 
   InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);
   String str;
   System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
   str = br.readLine();  
   System.out.println(str);
   System.out.println("Welcome to the world of Java Programming!"); 
  }
}
```

Basically, you first need to *declare a variable* before using it.
Like you need to declare a variable `InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(System.in);` before using it here `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);`.

Moreover start your learning from [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

In your buffered reader, you tried to reference the input stream reader, ip, before you defined it.
Just interchange those two lines.

```
InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```